# Should/Can I retract a paper that has fatal math error after this paper has been accepted, presented, and released in the proceeding?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science, errors-erratum, retraction

This paper has been accepted, presented in the top conference of computer science, and released in the proceeding since last month. However, recently, other readers find a fatal and ridiculous error in the proof. For this fatal error, I think I cannot amend it. Even if it can be amended, some important claims and nearly all proof steps will become total different.

Something to stress:

1, My claims and other proofs are motivated by the wrong proof rather than the experiments.

2, I then used experiments to demonstrate the correctness of the claims.

How can I handle it?

Comment: Just explaining the edit: When you withdraw a paper after it's published in the proceedings it's called "retraction" (before publication, it's withdrawal).

Comment: Have you examined the possibility of proving the other results without using the result with the flawed proof? As I understand from comments, the claims do have experimental support, even without any of the proofs.

Comment: Why have you edited your question to remove practically all of the content?

Comment: I have restored the content of the question. Questions and answers should be available for future visitors.

Comment: @mhwombat ... and it's gone again. Unfortunately I think this will just end up as a pointless edit war with the asker. A little more content left this time, but vital facts still deleted (e.g. that the claims are experimentally verified!). olivia, please could you explain why you are doing this?

Comment: Sorry. I hate my stupid stuffs.

Comment: @olivia We all do stupid stuff from time to time - that's ok. What matters is how you handle it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should you do if you spotted a non-trivial error in a highly cited paper?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18911/what-should-you-do-if-you-spotted-a-non-trivial-error-in-a-highly-cited-paper)

Answer (score 6):

For a journal paper you could either **retract** it, which means to "unpublish" it, or you could add an **erratum**, i.e. a short note where you explain what parts of the paper are wrong (and how to fix them, in case you know it) and which parts are still correct.

If I understood your case correctly, it seems like an erratum stating that the mathematical proof is incorrect, while the experiments still support the claim, would be appropriate.