# How to politely point out a basic mistake in a published top tier journal when working on some extension of the paper

Tags: journals

I have found a basic mistake in one of the published paper in a top tier Applied Mathematics journal. I have told my research supervisor about it and he also agrees with me. I found the issue when I was working on one open problem mentioned in the paper. Please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on the consequences of the mistake. Does it invalidate the main conclusions of the article or is it only a side issue? If the former, you can write up what the consequences are and present the new results as an article an submit it. If it is only a side issue, you can mention it in a footnote when writing up your results for the open problem.

In the former case, keep the tone professional: don't use any adjectives to describe the mistake and certainly not when refering to the authors, i.e. it is a mistake not a basic mistake. Focus on the point you want to make, and let the strength of the argument speak for itself.

Comment: Yes, it is the former. I have asked the authors, but they have not replied.

Comment: Sounds like you have an article to write. Just keep the tone professional: don't use any adjectives to describe the mistake and certainly not when refering to the authors, i.e. it is a mistake not a basic mistake. Focus on the point you want to make, and let the strength of the argument speak for itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of previous posts on math SE and academia SE that are relevant to your question: 
[Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180211/how-to-address-mistakes-in-published-papers) and [Post 2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18911/what-should-you-do-if-you-spotted-a-non-trivial-error-in-a-highly-cited-paper). The discussions following these posts are quite illuminating.

Although not an answer to your question, there is also this [article](http://www.nature.com/news/reproducibility-a-tragedy-of-errors-1.19264) that I found to be a very interesting read on addressing mistakes discovered in previously published papers.

Comment: It's helpful if you quote or summarize the contents of the linked article.